# hide load more button when post total reached

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, alpine.js

I have a ajax post loading program, I can load more post on click of a button.

The problem that I'm having is getting the button to hide or show less when no more post.

I can query out the post count in PHP as I have with my side bar bellow.

```php
<?php

foreach ($my_categories as $term_id) {
    $category = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'category');

    if ($category->slug != "all-articles") {
        if ($category->parent != 0) { // If this is a subcategory

            $args = array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'category' => $category->term_id,
                'post_type' => $new_string,
            );
            $count_posts = get_posts($args);
            $total_posts_child = count($count_posts);


            ?>
            <li :class="category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'child' : ''" ;>
                <a class="child" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html($category->name);
                    echo " "."(".$total_posts_child.")"; ?></a>
            </li> <?php

        } else {


            $args = array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'category' => $category->term_id,
                'post_type' => $new_string,
            );
            $count_posts = get_posts($args);
            $total_posts_parent = count($count_posts);

            ?>
            <li :class="category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'parent' : ''" ;>
                <a class="parent" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html($category->name);
                    echo " "."(".$total_posts_parent.")" ?></a>
            </li>   <?php
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I'm getting is trying to get that post count into JavaScript so I can hide my button if post count is reached.

```
 <div @click="loadMore()" x-show="total > (limit + offset)" class="text-center pt-4">
                 <button class="border border-solid border-slate-700 text-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-800 px-4 py-2"> Load More </button>
            </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 6,
    category: null,
    post_type_js: post_id,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    offset: 0,
    total:null,
    
    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
        this.total = 8;
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    
    loadMore() {
        this.loadingMore = true;
        this.total = 8;
        this.offset += 6;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
    },

    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
        formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); 

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
            formData.append("total", this.total);
        }

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        });
    },
    
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal();
}

}));
})
```

I have thought about scraping my HTML and getting the number, but honestly been thinking all day, I cant find a way to get the total post count for the category and post type clicked in the side bar

Comment: Not related to your problem in any way, but I find that mixing both `<?php echo` and `<?=` in the same file or even codebase very confusing. Honestly, I really don't even like short echo at all, and my team isn't allowed to use it, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: its a good point, I prefer echo, once this problem is solved ill go back and clean up the code. thanks @ChrisHaas

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by requesting one more row than I need and checking how many are returned.

So - if you want 6 more rows, set the limit to 7.

Now if you get less than 7 rows back, you know that there are no more rows after this set, so hide the 'More' button.

If you get 7 back, discard the last row and show the 'More' button, because you know that there is at least one more row after the current six.

Comment: ok, but the total post is dependent on the category, if i change category the number needs to change

Comment: You don't need to know the total.  Your fetchposts() function goes for 6 posts at a time, as far as I can see.  You need to change it to fetch 7 posts at a time, then if you get 7 posts, set a "show" boolean which makes the button visible, and discard the last (seventh) post.  If you get less than 7 posts, set the "show" boolean to false because you have reached the end of that category's posts.

Comment: Hmm not sure I fully understand, can you post a code snippet for me to try

Comment: OK, I've posted some code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never worked with wordpress, but if what you want is to get it in to javascript why not return it in your json, res.json(). I suppose another way would be to give the button an attribute like name = $total_posts_parent and then get that attribute in js with getAttribute(name) on an onlick method.

Comment: not sure the second option would work as needs to be dynamic if i change category, so needs to know the current category. the first one im struggling to get the post count, but that is how i was trying, cant seem to get it to work though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample showing how to fetch one more item than you need.  This tells you whether to leave the button visible.  You just discard the extra item.  This API has 100 products being retrieved in batches of 30.  So when the last 10 are showing, the button will be hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.13.7/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div x-data="products">
  <template x-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
    <div>
      <span x-text="product.id"></span>: <span x-text="product.title"></span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <button x-show="showButton" @click="getNext">Load more</button>
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('products',() => ({
    products: [],
    showButton: true,
    limit: 30,
    skip: 0,
    getNext () {
      const fetchLimit = this.limit + 1
      fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products?limit="+fetchLimit+"&skip="+this.skip+"&select=title")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          // If we got more than our limit, leave button visible and remove excess item  
          if (data.products.length > this.limit) {
            data.products.pop()
          } else {
            this.showButton = false
          }
          this.products = data.products
          this.skip += this.limit
        })
    },
    init() {
      this.getNext()
    }
  }))
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```